# changing state using $state.go doesn't apply scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an ionic angularJs app, where i need to change state on a button click. Apart from numerous other state's i have below two states which are.

```
.state('app.a', {
    url : "/base/a",
    views : {
        'myContent' : {
            templateUrl : "a.html",
            controller : 'MyController'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.b', {
    url : "/base/b",
    views : {
        'myContent' : {
            templateUrl : "b.html",
            controller : 'MyController'
        }
    }
})
```

Now in a.html i have a button that calls method clickMe().

```
$scope.clickMe = function () {
    $state.go('app.b');
    $scope.someVal = 20;
    //$timeout(function(){
    //  $scope.$apply();
    //}, 0);
}
```

b.html does load, however the value of someVal is just NOT reflected on b.html. One thing to note that if i put $scope.someVal = 20 outside clickMe() it does take effect (however, i need this to happen only on button click).

Not sure, seems to be quite straightforward to me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to put `$scope.someVal = 20` before the `state.go` ?

Comment: I think you have to put $scope.someVal = 20 before $state.go because in this order , he will make the redirection first.

Comment: Where is `$scope.clickMe` defined?

Comment: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/blocker-bug-with-state-go-navigation/11036

Comment: @carton he can't do this, as after applying $state.go() it will use a newer instance of the controller and this will need to have the new value, so he is doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a [bug in Ionic framework regarding using states with dot notation](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/blocker-bug-with-state-go-navigation/11036), also if you must set the value after changing the state you may consider using one of ui-router [events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#events-1), so when the state changed or starting to change you can update the $scope of the controller.

The most important thing is that every time you will create a new instance of the controller, then you must update the value after going to the state you are heading to.

Comment: $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //console.log(toState); // "lazy.state"
        if ( toState.name == 'app.b' ) {         }
    });     worked for me